# Drawing 3-D RGB cube model with Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I wrote this code to draw an RGB cube, but it's color not exact as true?

```
%Define a six row by four column matrix to define the six cube faces
fm = [1 2 6 5; 2 3 7 6; 3 4 8 7; 4 1 5 8; 1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8]

%Define an eight row by three column matrix to define the vertices at which
%the faces meet
vm = [0 0 0; 1 0 0; 1 1 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1; 0 1 1]

%Plot the cube ----- gives each face a different color and creates the cube at a convenient viewing angle
patch('Vertices',vm,'Faces',fm,'FaceVertexCData',hsv(8),'FaceColor','interp');
view(3);
```

[image: RGB cube]

Comment: What's wrong with the current output? Do you want constant (flat) colors on each face? Or is the problem with the `hsv` colormap?

Comment: no flat give me one color in each face i need it like this image , http://lodev.org/cgtutor/images/colorcube.jpg                                                                                                     I think problem in hsv ?!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: please , are you saw the uploaded image ? and how its differs from the drawn one ! I couldn't know what is the problem !!

Comment: Begging for help is not going to get people to help you on StackOverflow. Improving and clarifying your question (e.g., adding the image in your comment to your question) will. Then, don't expect instant responses. This is not a do-your-work-for-you service. It thrives on quality questions and answers, communication, and professionalism.

Comment: OK , sir thanks for your advise , Only this  was happen because of I am beginner to use this society thank for You . sorry if I do mistake .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time, I finished the code, @horchler's answer was online already. It looks perfect. Anyway posting mine as well.

To understand what colors you are applying, I printed values of hsv(8) as follows.

```
1.0000         0         0
1.0000    0.7500         0
0.5000    1.0000         0
     0    1.0000    0.2500
     0    1.0000    1.0000
     0    0.2500    1.0000
0.5000         0    1.0000
1.0000         0    0.7500
```

But what you want to apply actually is red, green, blue, white, and cyan, magenta, yellow, black. Please refer to [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html?refresh=true) to know about Matlab color codes. Hence we can apply the colors to each vertex manually based on your requirement. I changed your code as follows.

```
% Define a six row by four column matrix to define the six cube faces
fm = [1 2 6 5; 2 3 7 6; 3 4 8 7; 4 1 5 8; 1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8];

% Define an eight row by three column matrix to define the vertices at which
% the faces meet
vm = [0 0 0; 1 0 0; 1 1 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1; 0 1 1];

% Plot the cube ----- gives each face a different color and creates the 
% cube at a convenient viewing angle
clear cdata;
cdata = [
    0 0 0; % black
    1 0 0; % red
    1 0 1; % magenta
    0 0 1; % blue
    0 1 0; % green
    1 1 0; % yellow
    1 1 1; % white
    0 1 1; % cyan
    ];

patch('Vertices',vm,'Faces',fm,'FaceVertexCData',cdata,'FaceColor','interp');

axis equal;
axis off;
view(3);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice. The colors of your vertices don't quite match those in the [image posted by the OP](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/images/colorcube.jpg), though I'm not sure how important that is.

Comment: @horchler yes, you have done a great job by correctly matching the colors exactly as the given figure. I would recommend yours as the answer as it matches the question well.

Answer (score 4):

It is the color map that needs to be updated to get your plot to look like the one in [your link](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/images/colorcube.jpg). You can't simply use a built-in function to directly generate the right sequence. Additionally, calling `hsv(8)` produces additional colors that you don't want (print it out in the Command Window to see), but doesn't include pure white or black. You can use `hsv(6)` and append `[0 0 0]` and `[1 1 1]`, but you'll need to make sure the ordering aligns with the rest of your code (`fm` and `vm`).

Here's a revised version of your code – the `cm` matrix encodes the pattern of colors for each vertex:

```
% Define a six row by four column matrix to define the six cube faces
fm = [1 2 6 5;
      2 3 7 6;
      3 4 8 7;
      4 1 5 8;
      1 2 3 4;
      5 6 7 8];

% Define an eight row by three column matrix to define the vertices at which the faces meet
vm = [0 0 0;
      1 0 0;
      1 1 0;
      0 1 0;
      0 0 1;
      1 0 1;
      1 1 1;
      0 1 1];

% RGB colors for each vertex
cm = [0 0 0;
      0 1 0;
      1 1 0;
      1 0 0;
      0 0 1;
      0 1 1;
      1 1 1;
      1 0 1];

% Plot the cube - gives each face a different color and creates the cube at a convenient viewing angle
figure('Color','w')
patch('Vertices',vm,'Faces',fm,'FaceVertexCData',cm,'FaceColor','interp');
view(120,30);

% Plot axes
axis equal;
axis off;
d1 = 1.25;
line([0 0 0;d1 0 0],[0 0 0;0 d1 0],[0 0 0;0 0 d1],'Color','k','LineWidth',2);

% Label axes
d2 = 0.1;
text([0 1 0],[1 -d2 -d2],[-d2 0 1],'255','FontSize',11,'HorizontalAlignment','center');
text([0 d1 0],[d1 d2 d2],[d2 0 d1],{'R','G','B'},'FontSize',16);
```

This results in a figure that looks like this

[image: 3-D RGB cube plot]